# pm2 hangs and unable to restart process due to high numbers of request

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, server, ubuntu-16.04, pm2

For the purpose of load testing i created an API which request around 2000 bookings at a time and after hitting this API, server(AWS EC2 instance) reaches to the more than 20% of CPU consumption and consume almost all the memory(900/991M) of system. After that i was trying to restart node app with pm2 restart but it's not working and even "pm2 ls" and "pm2 log" commands are also not working. What can i do now to run my application again ?
List of command which i already run on server.

```
pm2 restart pid && pm2 log pid
pm2 ls
pm2 log pid
```

Comment: Can you share the error message?

Comment: No error message was there it just got hanged over there. I disconnected server (via terminal) and after that when i again tried to connection via SSH it was refusing connection.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue? I'm still experiencing it with version 5.2.2. It goes so far, that even `ps -aux` or `ls` command is not executing anymore and gives me the error: `-bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable`

Answer (score 9):

Try to kill the current process of pm2:

```
ps -ef | grep pm2
kill -9 <PID_OF_PM2>
```

And then restart pm2 again.

Try to Upgrade to the latest pm2 version if the above not working after killing the pm2 process, using this command:

```
npm install pm2@latest -g
```

Answer (score 0):

PM2 hangs when your project contains millions of files and it is watching all those files. Make sure to exclude the non-essential files from watch using ignore_watch.